# Insert javascript variable as background image source

Tags: javascript, variables, background-image

I have a variable that I can display on the page by using the following
    `<script>document.write(image)</script>`

I can copy the result to the browser and it displays the file I require.

What I want to do is to take that variable and use it to specify the src of my background image

```
`<p style="background-image: url(**image**);">`
```

I know that this is probably simple to you guys, but I have spent the whole day and am losing a lot of hair over this one. Thanks for your time....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the element is selectable :

```
<p id="paragraph">Some text</p>
```

You can change the style with javascript:

```
document.getElementById('paragraph').style.background = 'url('+image+')';
```

if you're creating the paragraph you can do:

```
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.style.background = 'url('+image+')';
```

Comment: As you guys usually say if we DUMMIES out here asked the right questions, you could probably give us the right answers.... –

Answer (score 7):

Give the `<p>` element an id:

```
<p id="myPElement">
```

Manipulate it in the dom...

```
document.getElementById('myPElement').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image + ')';
```

... or with jquery:

```
$('#myPElement').css('background-image', 'url(' + image + ')');
```

Comment: As you guys usually say if we DUMMIES out here asked the right questions, you could probably give us the right answers....

Answer (score 0):

I didn't give enough background in my original question...

ie; I forgot to mention that I was attempting to do this in the middle of a server side loop.

I achived what I had set out to do with the following code

```
`<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<table background=\"http://..../Pages/"+image+"/bkg.jpg\" >");`
```

Thank you VERY much for your help !!